# When do we need to use 'finishTasksAndInvalidate' for NSUrlSession?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I call under mentioned code when my app is notified by entering to background:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                            selector: @selector(handleDidEnterBackground)
                            name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                            object: nil];
```

I have following code snippet `handleDidEnterBackground`:

```
NSURLSession *session;

// ...

sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"com.my.company"];
sessionConfiguration.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
sessionConfiguration.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = NO;
session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration 
            delegate:self 
       delegateQueue:nil];


NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
    [task resume];
 // why do I need this line?   
[session finishTasksAndInvalidate];
```

---

From Doc:

```
/* -finishTasksAndInvalidate returns immediately and existing tasks will be allowed  
* to run to completion.  New tasks may not be created.  The session  
* will continue to make delegate callbacks until URLSession:didBecomeInvalidWithError:  
* has been issued.   
*
* -finishTasksAndInvalidate and -invalidateAndCancel do not  
* have any effect on the shared session singleton.  
*  
* When invalidating a background session, it is not safe to create another background  
* session with the same identifier until URLSession:didBecomeInvalidWithError: has  
* been issued.
  */
- (void)finishTasksAndInvalidate;
```

I try to read it again and again but fail to understand the usage. Can somebody spread the light on this API?

Comment: That call prevents other parts of your app from starting new tasks.  Unless I'm misremembering, it isn't strictly necessary.